# Change the # of image in bx slider on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, bxslider

I am using bx slider but the problem is that when i resize the window, the images in slider should change according to window size..

```
I have tried the below code and it works but every time I have to reload the page, can anybody help me please. And thanks in advance.

<script type="text/javascript">
   if ($(window).width() < 480 ) {  
       $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#slider1').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 280,
    minSlides: 2,
    maxSlides: 2,
    startSlide: 0,
    slideMargin: 10
      });
        });
   }

   else if ($(window).width() > 480 ) {

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#slider1').bxSlider({
   slideWidth: 280,
   minSlides: 4,
   maxSlides: 4,
   startSlide: 0,
   slideMargin: 10
  });
});
    }
else {
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#slider1').bxSlider({
  slideWidth: 280,
  minSlides: 4,
  maxSlides: 4,
  startSlide: 0,
  slideMargin: 10
 });
});
}           
</script>
```

Comment: $('#slider1').bxSlider({
         slideWidth: 280,
         minSlides: 2,
         maxSlides: 4,
         startSlide: 0,
         slideMargin: 10
        });
only this will work out no need to put it for every size

Comment: I have tried this but it will cut the image if i ll see in Ipad..
Thanks @rrugbys

Comment: [link](http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-dynamic-number-slides)
Plz check this link and resize the window the image will cut

Answer (score 1):

First make put your slider into a var (better for later "reloadSlider"), then make your life easier by creating var-s for your settings (since you will need them at least twice).

Finally you need a  $( window ).resize function.

See if it works (I didn't test it but should work since I have just completed mine - kind of more complicated to show it).

Try this (by the way, I see that 'medium' and 'big' sizes have same settings...):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var slider;

   var defsOne   = { slideWidth: 280, minSlides: 2, maxSlides: 2, startSlide: 0, slideMargin: 10 }
   var defsTwo   = { slideWidth: 280, minSlides: 4, maxSlides: 4, startSlide: 0, slideMargin: 10 }
   var defsThree = { slideWidth: 280, minSlides: 4, maxSlides: 4, startSlide: 0, slideMargin: 10 }
   var myDefs = {};

   $(document).ready(function(){
       if ($(window).width() < 480 ) {  
           myDefs = defsOne;
       }

       else if ($(window).width() > 480 ) {
           myDefs = defsTwo;
       }
       else {
           myDefs = defsThree;
       }
       slider = $('#slider1').bxSlider(myDefs);
   });


   $( window ).resize(function() {
       var ww = $(window).width();
       if ($(window).width() < 480 ) {  
           myDefs = defsOne;
       }

       else if ($(window).width() > 480 ) {
           myDefs = defsTwo;
       }
       else {
           myDefs = defsThree;
       }

       slider.reloadSlider( myDefs );

   });

</script>
```

Actually I would not slider.reloadSlider() at every resize (at every window pixel change), put somewhere a flag to check if size really changed from previously used one and only then do the reload:

```
if ( sizeReallyChanged ) {
    slider.reloadSlider( myDefs );
}
```

If you don't you are going to reload it tons of times ...

Of some extra-help could be setting an object for "global settings" - since yours are all almost the same an then :

```
var defsGlobal = { slideWidth: 280, startSlide: 0, slideMargin: 10 }
var defsOne    = { minSlides: 2, maxSlides: 2 }
var defsTwo    = { minSlides: 4, maxSlides: 4 }
```

and finally "connect" all of them (of in the right place i.e. 'if'):

```
...
   wholeDefs = $.extend( {} , defsOne, defsGlobal);
...
   slider = $('#slider1').bxSlider(wholeDefs);
...
```

Hope this could help,
Bye nIc

Comment: After some good hours of searching for a good solution to this problem, finding your answer has finally ended my searches. This is absolutely awesome. You rock! Great work, so clean and visible and easy to follow. Congratulations and many many thanks.